# Using namecheap domain name for AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, namecheap

I have an application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I'm trying to route a domain I own from namecheap to the production environment. I followed the documentation from AWS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html), but I feel kind of lost after going through it.

In Route 53, I have a hosted zone record name `mydomain.io` that is setting Value/Route traffic to `my-aws-env.eba-fz3ggfhd.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com`. When I go to `mydomain.io` I still see the namecheap landing page. I feel like there's something I need to do on the namecheap end to allow the traffic to be routed to aws, but I didn't see anything else in the docs. What piece am I missing?

Comment: How long did you wait for the change to propagate?

Comment: Ultimately, though, for help configuring your namecheap domain name, you should be asking namecheap.

Comment: We're not going to be able to help much without knowing the domain, or at least seeing a sanitised version of the result of a `dig`, though.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I waited a half hour or so, but posted this question because it seemed like there was something I was missing as I didn't do anything within namecheap

Comment: Half an hour is really not a very long time. Domain data tends to have Times-To-Live of more like 48 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are seeing the Namecheap landing page, your name servers are incorrect. You mention following the instructions to route traffic from Route 53 to Elastic Beanstalk, but nowhere do you mention that your domain is actually pointing to Route 53. The Namecheap landing page confirms this as you would not be getting that from Route 53.

Check your NS records in your Route 53 Hosted Zone and configure those as your name servers in Namecheap. You might have to give it some time to update, but that should solve your problem.

Comment: It looks like that's what I was missing. I just added the name servers in namecheap and am now waiting for the changes to propagate.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to redirect using Route 53. I was able to bypass it.

## What's needed

1. ElasticBeanstalk App

> **URL:** `my-aws-env.eba-fz3ggfhd.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com`
> 2. Namespace domain

To map your Beanstalk App to your Namecheap domain, you'll need to IPV4 for your URL which can be obtained using https://www.whatismyip.com/dns-lookup/

Once you have your `IP V4`, do the following in your Namecheap account

## What to Change

Go to Namecheap Advance settings

1. Go to Advanced DNS
2. Make changes to host records (Map to your Elastic Beanstalk `IP V4`)

| Type | Host | Value | TTL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A Record | @ | `IP V4` | 5 min |
| A Record | www | `IP V4` | 5 min |

Give it 5-10 minutes.
You should now be able to access your Elastic Beanstalk instance from your Namecheap domain.

Answer (score 1):

if your domain is at Namechip then you not need to do anything with route53..

you simply need to point your domain to Your Public IP.

Add **A** record with your **public IP** in DNS management at Namechip